# Maximum number of categories

Tags: categories

I'm planning a site that will have approximately 10,000 categories in the installation.Does ExpressionEngine allow this? Is there a maximum number of categories allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no maximum number of categories in EE. However, if you have 10k categories in a group, the Publish Form will get quite unwieldy, listing out all of the categories in a list.

You might want to look at add-ons like [Categories Field](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/categories-field) to improve on the default interface, or perhaps use [Relationships](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/relationships.html) rather than Categories.